# Global log level in Crystal

Tags: logging, crystal-lang

I'm writing an application in the Crystal programming language. One of the things I like about Crystal is its extensive standard library, which includes things like a `Logger` utility.

The logging syntax looks like this:

```
require "logger"

log = Logger.new(STDOUT)
log.level = Logger::WARN

log.debug("Created logger")
log.info("Program started")
log.warn("Nothing to do!")
```

([Taken from Crystal documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.21.1/Logger.html))

The problem I'm running into is that it is hard to keep track of severity levels. Either I have to pass the same `Logger` object to whatever class/method I want logging in, or I have to pass the severity enum.

How should I deal with this issue? Is there an accepted solution in the Crystal community?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place the logger on a class, for example

```
module MyApp
  class_getter logger = Logger.new.tap { |l| l.level = Logger::WARN }
end
```

Then use it with `MyApp.logger.info("foo")`.

However this has a few drawbacks:

1. The logging level is global, you can't edit it per-class.
2. Logging within libraries is impossible (they can't see `MyApp`)

Maybe it would be worth opening an issue on the Crystal repo to discuss this.